# Should the structure of a derived obj file coinside with the naming of the original step file?

Tags: wavefront, autodesk-forge, autodesk-model-derivative

When using the Model Derivative API I successfully generate an obj representation from a step file. But within that process are some quirks that I do not fully understand:

1. The Post job has a `output.advanced.exportFileStructure` property which can be set to `"multiple"` and a `output.advanced.objectIds` property which lets you specify the which parts of the model you would like to extract. From the little that the documentation states, I would expect to receive one obj file per requested objectid. Which from my experience is not the case. So does this only work for compressed files like `.iam` and `.ipt`?
2. Well, anyway, instead I get one obj file for all objectIds with one polygon group per objectId. The groups are named (duh!), so I would expect them to be named like their objectId but it seams like the numbers are assigned in a random way. So how should I actually map an objectId to its corresponding 3d part? Is there any way to link the information from GET :urn/metadata/:guid/properties back to their objects?

I hope somebody can shine light on this. If you need more information I can provide you with the original step file, the obj and my server log.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You misunderstood the objectIds property of the derivatives API: specifying that field allows you to export only specific components to a single obj, for example your car model has 1000 different components, but you just want to export components that represent the engine: [34, 56, 76] (I just made those up...). If you want to export each objectId to a separate obj file, you need to fire multiple jobs. the "exportFileStructure" option only applies to composite designs (i.e. assemblies) single: creates one OBJ file for all the input files (assembly file), multiple: creates a separate OBJ file for each object. A step file is not a composite design.

As you noticed the obj groups are named randomly. As far as I know there is no easy reliable way to map a component in the obj file to the original objectId because .obj is a very basic format and it doesn't support metadata. You could use a geometric approach (finding where is the component in space, use bounding boxes, ...) to achieve the mapping but it could be challenging with complex models.

Comment: Ok, that was the answer I was afraid of. So basically if would extract single objs I would waste all my cloud credits in basically no time.
I thought it would make sense to name the poly groups after their objectId. I guess this would not be difficult as the object id is just a 1 based index and the group name after the `g` line prefix can obviously be just a number.
Do you think that there may be any chance that such a feature will be implemented in the future?

Comment: It would be a pity if not. Because this little detail prevents me from using any game engine in conjunction with forge in a meaningfull manner.

Comment: Sure, I agree that would be a better approach than a random naming. I've logged this request in our system for the development team. I can't commit to guarantee you it will be implemented sooner or later but you now have a chance :)

Comment: Thank you. Is there any official changelog for the Model Derivative API that I can follow? I can't find anything on developer.autodesk.com.

Comment: That should be under the "Overview/Recent Changes" section like for data API: https://developer.autodesk.com/en/docs/data/v2/overview/, but unfortunately it's not there for Derivatives, so I will also bring that to their attention ...